# USB tethering faster than WiFi tethering with VPN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, modem

I've been scratching my head trying to figure this one out.

I have a sim card with unlimited data access however, after a certain limit, the operator throttles the connection speed to about 512 Kbps. When I tether my iPhone (5s) to my Mac via USB and use a VPN, I can get around the speed throttling and access the full bandwidth (about 15 Mbps). But if I tether using WiFi and use the same VPN, it doesn't work. As I understand, while tethering, my phone is merely acting as a modem to connect to the network and the mac itself doesn't have any role in that side of the process.

I'm sure that the speed is not being affected by the transfer speeds of the usb vs wifi, because if I use the sim card in a [3g dongle](http://www.enter-world.com/product/hard-wi-fi-datacard-model-no-e-u3/) and use the VPN, the speeds are still slow.

I'm not so much trying to get around the throttling as I am trying to understand how the tech is working. So, I would be happy even if someone tells me it can't be done but does tell me how the tech is working.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind leaving a comment explaining?

Comment: I don't know about USB tethering but for WiFi tethering the iPhone usually uses a different APN to connect to the network - it does NOT simply act as a modem. Whether it's detected using APN settings or something else depends on your operator. There are a lot of factors operators can use to determine if you are tethering.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something very similar. I have a sim card with unlimited data / no limit. The iPhone itself reaches up to 40Mbps here on LTE. When I tether my iPhone 6s to my Macbook via USB I get the full LTE speed for my location as well (around 40Mbps). If I tether using WiFi it caps out at about 5Mbps.

It also caps out at 5.x Mbps if I put this sim card in a portable LTE router and connect the Macbook via WiFi to that LTE router. This holds true regardless if I use a VPN or not. Doesn't make a difference.

My current working theory is that the iPhone doesn't decrement the packet TTL when in USB tether mode, but it does so when in WiFi tether mode. So I'm guessing my network operator checks the TTL of the packets and adds a cap if the TTL doesn't match a certain schema.